# Configure apt-get unable to install specific package without version mentioning

Tags: debian, apt-get

Is there a way to configure `apt-get` to make unable to install specific package without setting version?

So, as a user I want to get an error if version is unspecified for package `X` only:

- `apt-get install X` - returns error;
- `apt-get install X=1.3.2-5` - installed package successfully;
- `apt-get install Y` - installed latest version of `Y` package.

Comment: I think exactly what you want is impossible to implement, but you could use the so-called ["APT pinning"](http://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences) to "pin" the packages of interest to specific versions so that they will be preferred when being installed without specifying a precise version. (Well, I'm just guessing your real use case...)